# chromadb.errors.NoIndexException: Index not found, please create an instance before querying

Tags: duckdb, langchain, chromadb

What does this mean?

How can I load the following index?

```
tree  langchain/
langchain/
├── chroma-collections.parquet
├── chroma-embeddings.parquet
└── index
    ├── id_to_uuid_cfe8c4e5-8134-4f3d-a120-0510e189004f.pkl
    ├── index_cfe8c4e5-8134-4f3d-a120-0510e189004f.bin
    ├── index_metadata_cfe8c4e5-8134-4f3d-a120-0510e189004f.pkl
    └── uuid_to_id_cfe8c4e5-8134-4f3d-a120-0510e189004f.pkl

1 directory, 6 files
```

From the following code snippet:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ABS_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    DB_DIR = os.path.join(ABS_PATH, 'langchain/index/index_cfe8c4e5-8134-4f3d-a120-0510e189004f.bin')
    client_settings = chromadb.config.Settings(
        chroma_db_impl="duckdb+parquet",
        persist_directory=DB_DIR,
        anonymized_telemetry=True
    )
    fp = './all_files.txt'
    embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
    get_vectorstore = lambda: Chroma(
            collection_name="langchain",
            embedding_function=embeddings,
            client_settings=client_settings,
            persist_directory=DB_DIR,
        )

    if not os.path.exists(fp):
        root_dir = "."  # Replace with the desired root directory
        gitignore_path = os.path.join(root_dir, ".gitignore")
        ignored_patterns = get_ignored_patterns(gitignore_path)
        files = []
        concatenated_content = ""
        for file_path in find_files(root_dir, "*.py", ignored_patterns):
            files.append(file_path)
            with open(file_path, "r") as file:
                file_content = file.read()
                file_section = f"# <START> {file_path}\n{file_content}\n# <END> {file_path}\n"
                concatenated_content += file_section
        with open('all_files.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(concatenated_content)
        loader = TextLoader(fp)
        docs = []
        for loader in [loader]:
            docs.extend(loader.load())
        splitter = _get_default_text_splitter()
        sub_docs = splitter.split_documents(docs)
        vectorstore = get_vectorstore().from_documents(sub_docs, embeddings, persist_directory='./langchain', collection_name='langchain')
        index = VectorStoreIndexWrapper(vectorstore=get_vectorstore())
    else:
        # the defaults
        index = VectorStoreIndexWrapper(vectorstore=get_vectorstore())
    breakpoint()
    print(index)
```

```
python embed.py 
Using embedded DuckDB with persistence: data will be stored in: /home/jm/pycharm_projects/test/langchain/index/index_cfe8c4e5-8134-4f3d-a120-0510e189004f.bin
> /home/jm/pycharm_projects/test/embed.py(78)<module>()
-> print(index)
(Pdb) index.query('hello')
*** chromadb.errors.NoIndexException: Index not found, please create an instance before querying
(Pdb)
```

Reference:

- https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/discussions/2901

Answer (score 1):

Since the Langchain's FAISS Vector store already has the "load_local" function implemented, I opted to use FAISS instead of Chroma.
It worked perfectly without any issues.

```
# Assuming your local path is "../data/faiss"
vector_store = FAISS.load_local("../data/faiss", embeddings=embeddings)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from langchain.indexes import VectorstoreIndexCreator

index = VectorstoreIndexCreator().from_loaders([loader])
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you know off hand, does this recreate the index each time on startup? I was only trying to reload the already generated index.

Answer (score 0):

it could be because your embedding is not loaded properly.

You could see such message if its suceess:

```
INFO:clickhouse_connect.json_impl:Using orjson library for writing JSON byte strings
```

INFO:chromadb.db.duckdb:loaded in 77 embeddings
INFO:chromadb.db.duckdb:loaded in 1 collections

In case of any issue it will be loaded in 0 embeddings

Answer (score 0):

From the discussion from the [GitHub](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/discussions/2901) issue this worked for me

created persisted indexing

```
chroma = Chroma.from_documents(
            collection_name="chroma_db",
            documents=docs,
            embedding=emb,
            persist_directory=os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, "chroma_db"),

        )
chroma.persist()
chroma = None
```

then using persisted indexing

```
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
vector_store = Chroma(
            collection_name='chroma_db',
            persist_directory=os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, "chroma_db"),
            embedding_function=embeddings
)
retriever = vector_store.as_retriever(
            search_type="similarity_score_threshold",
            search_kwargs={"k": 2, "score_threshold": 0.6}
        )
        sources = retriever.get_relevant_documents(query, return_metadata=True)
```